# Jubula test suite using old/stale data from test case's data set

Tags: java, testing, jubula

I ran into a problem where when I edited the data in a test case's "Data Sets" tab that running the test suite which uses the test case would use the old data; even after entirely deleting the row in question from the table that step still got used.

I'm using the standalone version, version 8.3.0.122.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the test case from the test suite and then adding it back in again fixes the problem.

Comment: Could you edit your question to tell which version of Jubula you are using? I faced the same problem in standalone version 2.4